# using regex to exclude specified text to extract certain numbers like left()/Right() functions in excel

Tags: regex

i have a list of transactions here:

| Transaction | REGEX(Amount) |
| --- | --- |
| Amount: 0.99 USD , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 73 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 133 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 100 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 101 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 6 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 104 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 57 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 61 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 12 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 12888.9 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 144 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 75 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 904 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 13.99 USD , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 90 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 10 USD , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 106 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 66 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 508 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |
| Amount: 21.95 SAR , 02:04:2021 |  |

and I want to use regex to extract the amounts only without the Currency

so far I've used this "(\d+.\d+ (?:USD)|\d+.\d+ SAR|\d+ USD|\d+ SAR)"

and this gave me the amount with the currency.

I'm new at using Regex is there a way to have it exclude the currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the currency only in capture group 1:

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?) (SAR|USD)
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digit with an optional part (note to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally)
- `)` Close group 1
- `(SAR|USD)` Match a space and either SAR or USD

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dxn3GY/1)

If the amount is always preceded by a space, you can match it before group 1 (the square brackets are for clarity only)

```
[ ](\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(SAR|USD)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rfEHY/1)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works (\d+.\d+[ USD]|\d+.\d+[ SAR]|\d+[ USD]|\d+[ SAR]) but im wondering if there is a simpler expression

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `(\d+(?:.\d+)?)\s(SAR|USD)` if it's only to match one of those two... otherwise `(\d+(?:.\d+)?)\s[A-Z]{3}` might be good if you want to match any 3 uppercase-characters there.

This will extract digits and any decimals into the first group.